# Simultaneous numerical fit of two equations using Numpy least square method

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, least-squares

I am trying to fit below mentioned two equations using python leastsq method but am not sure whether this is the right approach. First equation has incomplete gamma function in it while the second one is slightly complex, and along with an exponential function contains a term which is obtained by using a separate fitting formula.

```
J_mg = T_incomplete(hw/T_mag)
J_nmg = e^(-hw/T)*g(w,T)
```

Here g is a function of w and T and is calucated using a given fitting formula.
I am following the steps outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820715/simultaneous-data-fitting-in-python-with-leastsq) question.

Here is what I have done

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
from scipy.special import gammaincc
from scipy.special import gamma
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot


# generating data

NPTS = 10
hw = np.linspace(0.5, 10, NPTS)
j1 = np.linspace(0.001,10,NPTS)
j2 = np.linspace(0.003,10,NPTS)
T_mag = np.linspace(0.3,0.5,NPTS)

#defining functions

def calc_gaunt_factor(hw,T):
    fitting_coeff= np.loadtxt('fitting_coeff.txt', skiprows=1)
    #T is in KeV
    #K_b = 8.6173303(50)e−5 ev/K

    g = 0
    gamma = 0.0136/T
    theta= hw/T
    A= (np.log10(gamma**2) +0.5)*0.4
    B= (np.log10(theta)+1.5)*0.4
    for i in range(11):
        for j in range(11):
            g_ij = fitting_coeff[i][j]*(A**i)*(B**j)
            g = g_ij+g        
    return g

def j_w_mag(hw,T_mag):
    order= 0.001
    return np.sqrt(1/T_mag)*gamma(order)*gammaincc(order,hw/T_mag)

def j_w_nonmag(hw,T):
    gamma = 0.0136/T
    theta= hw/T
    return np.sqrt(1/T)*np.exp((-hw)/T)*calc_gaunt_factor(hw,T)

def residual_func(T,T_mag,hw,j1,j2):
    err_unmag = np.nan_to_num(j1 - j_w_nonmag(hw,T))
    err_mag = np.nan_to_num(j2 - j_w_mag(hw,T_mag))
    err= np.concatenate((err_unmag, err_mag))
    return err


par_init = np.array([.35])

best, cov, info, message, ler = leastsq(residual_func,par_init,args=(T_mag,hw,j1,j2),full_output=True)

print("Best-Fit Parameters:")
print("T=%s" %(best[0]))
```

I am getting weird value for my fitting parameter, T. Is this the right approach? Thanks.

Comment: I am unable to run the code without the specified file named "fitting_coeff.txt", would you please add a link to it - or if it is small add the contents to the question?

Comment: @JamesPhillips It's basically a text file with all coefficients. Here is the pastebin link https://pastebin.com/HAqh93Zi

Comment: When I place this line at the top of your code "import warnings;warnings.filterwarnings('error')" I get more detail on the problem, showing that np.sqrt(1/T) is receiving an invalid, or negative, number.